# If the child process alters its file descriptor table, does it affect the parent's?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I'm writing a C program that involves forking a child process to call dup2 to intercept stdout to write to a file. I was wondering if the child process alters the file descriptor table for the parent process if I call dup2(fd, 1). Would it alter the FD table for the parent, or because the child has a copy of the table it would be fine?

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't, and that's the point. If you seek an fd, it affects the parent though, because it really is two handles to the same open file descriptor.